# Bootstrap side white space

Tags: html, css

So for a school project im making a website but whenever I use  container and container-fluid no matter what I use i have these empty spaces on the side and I have no clue how to fix them so i came here for help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="nav">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="nav1">
          <header class="nav-inverse">
            <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Domov</a>
                  </li>
                </div>
              </div>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Življenjepis</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Obdobje</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Nagrade</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Vizitka</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </header>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-2">
        <div class="container fluid" id="body1">
          <h1 id="Header1">Hello</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I do hope I can find help here and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you including Bootstrap CSS twice and not including jQuery which Bootstrap JS requires?

Comment: Can u provide an image of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap adds in some spacing by default to `container` and `container-fluid` classes. To remove these, you can specify you want no padding / margin on each item by adding a class using the format `{property}{sides}-{size}` where size is 0.

For example, to remove padding you can add a `p-0` class. You can also remove a specific side:

- `pt-0` top
- `pr-0` right
- `pb-0` bottom
- `pb-0` left

Similarly, to remove margin you can add a `m-0` class.

For more info on spacing, check out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 1):

To remove these default spacing use bootstrap grid classes can be removed with `.no-gutters`.

Here is an example

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

For more information: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by white spaces, you might want to define with an image. If you mean that your body doesn't fill the page, the problem is nested `container`s. See comments below.

```html
<body>
    <!-- This container is going to "add space" to your sides. -->
    <div class="container" id="nav">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- This will fill all 12 columns on XL viewport,
                 but the columns are inside the parent container. -->
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <!-- This will go to the limits of the parent container above. -->
                <div class="container-fluid" id="nav1">
                    <header class="nav-inverse">
                    <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Domov</a>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    </div>                 
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Življenjepis</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Obdobje</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Nagrade</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="https://www.stps-trbovlje.si/">Vizitka</a>
                    </li>

                    </ul>
                </header>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-2">
                <div class="container fluid" id="body1">
                    <h1 id="Header1">Hello</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```